# bash - `read` cannot read from a redirect, `cat` works fine?

Tags: bash, exec, at-command

I've been trying to send some AT commands to my modem and want to capture response into a variable. Here's my code:

```
exec 3<>/dev/ttyUSB3

echo -e "AT+CGSN\n" >&3

cat <&3
#read -r RESPONSE <&3
#echo "Response was $RESPONSE"

exec 3<&-
exec 3>&-
```

Results:

```
$ ./imei_checker.sh 
AT+CGSN


356538041935676



OK

AT+CGSN


356538041935676



OK
```

But if I change `cat` to `read`, it doesn't work:

```
$ ./imei_checker.sh 
Response was AT+CGSN
```

2 more questions:

1. Why it show the dupplicate output?
2. How do I close the file handle properly? `exec 3<&-` and `exec 3>&-`
   seems doesn't work. I have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to
   get control of the Terminal back.

Comment: Accepted practice is to _update_ questions with information pertinent to the original question. If it's a whole _different_ issue, it should be a new question. Backing out the update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read` will only read a single line, unlike `cat` which will basically read and echo until end of file.

For a `read` version, you're best off reading with a timeout up until the point you get the `OK` (and storing any line that contains a lot of digits).

I think you'll find that it's not the closing of the number 3 file handle that's stopping things - it's more likely to be the `cat` which will *continue* to read/echo until an end-of-file event that isn't happening.

You can be certain of this if you just put:

```
echo XYZZY
```

immediately before the closing `exec` statements. If it's still in the `cat`, you'll never see it.

So, using a looping `read` version will probably fix that as well.

---

By way of example, here's how you can use `read` to do this with standard input:

```
#!/bin/bash

NUM=
while true ; do
    read -p "> " -t 10 -r RESP <&0
    if [[ $? -ge 128 ]] ; then RESP=OK ; fi
    echo "Entered: $RESP"
    if [[ $RESP = OK ]] ; then break ; fi

    if [[ $RESP =~ ^[0-9] ]] ; then NUM=$RESP ; fi
done

echo "Finished, numerics were: '$NUM'"
```

It uses the timeout feature of `read` to detect if there's no more input (setting the input to `OK` so as to force loop exit). If you *do* get an `OK` before then, it exits normally anyway, the timeout simply caters for the possibility that the modem doesn't answer as expected.

The number is set initially to nothing but overwritten by any line from the "modem" that starts with a number.

Two sample runs, with and without an `OK` response from the "modem":

```
pax> ./testprog.sh
> hello
Entered: hello
> 12345
Entered: 12345
> OK
Entered: OK
Finished, numerics were: '12345'

pax> ./testprog.sh
> hello
Entered: hello
> now we wait 10 secs
Entered: now we wait 10 secs
> Entered: OK
Finished, numerics were: ''
```

It wouldn't be too hard to convert that to something similar with you modem device (either `read <&3` or `read -u3` will work just fine).

---

That would basically translate to your environment as:

```
exec 3<>/dev/ttyUSB3
echo -e "AT+CGSN\n" >&3
NUM=
while true ; do
    read -t 10 -r RESP <&3
    if [[ $? -ge 128 ]] ; then RESP=OK ; fi
    echo "Entered: $RESP"
    if [[ $RESP = OK ]] ; then break ; fi
    if [[ $RESP =~ ^[0-9] ]] ; then NUM=$RESP ; fi
done
echo "Finished, numerics were: '$NUM'"
exec 3<&-
exec 3>&-
```

Now I haven't *tested* that since I don't have a modem hooked up (been on broadband for quite a while now) but it should be *close* to what you need, if not exact.

Answer (score 1):

`read` takes the descriptor to read from as the argument following `-u`. See `help read` for details.

Comment: `read -r -u3 RESPONSE` give the same results (*Response was AT+CGSN*).

Comment: Only one. I'm sorry, what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the individual lines into variables I'd suggest to wrap `read` into a `while`:

```
while read -r RESPONSE <&3; do
  echo "Response was $RESPONSE"
  ## e.g.:
  [ "$RESPONSE" = "OK" ] && break
done
```

However, if you want "everything" that is sent back to you to reside in `$RESPONSE` you could do it like this:

```
RESPONSE="$(cat <&3)"
```

Comment: I'd still suggest putting a timeout on the read in case the modem decides not to send you an `OK` line. In addition, for reasons pointed out in my answer, that last one (the `cat`) probably won't work simply because the file handle is not being closed by the modem. In other words, it will seem to hang because it'll just wait around forever for the modem to finish up. The `read` solution is the right one, I believe.

Comment: @bitmask: with your above code, the response still seems to be messed up. It shows the different results after each run.